# copyFromRecordset is changing formats in other worksheets

Tags: sql, excel, adodb, vba

A VBA macro I've been using for months suddenly started reformatting cells in unrelated worksheets to Date format. I went through the code to find the offending line, and it seems to be the "copyFromRecordset" function. See below for the relevant snippit. Yes, this simple, straightforward code is creating this odd problem.

```
Dim adRs As ADODB.Recordset
Set adRs = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim SQLQuery As String 
SQLQuery = "SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM Table;"
On Error GoTo OpenFailed
adRs.Open SQLQuery, adConn, adOpenStatic, adLockPessimistic         
If Not (adRs.BOF And adRs.EOF) Then
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:O300").CopyFromRecordset adRs
End If
```

Following similar problems, here are steps that I have tried.

1. I made sure that all of the affected cells have a specific number format and are not set to "General"
2. I deleted all custom number formats in the workbook
3. I made sure that there were no number formats associated with "Normal" or any other used cell style.

Also, it seems that the number of rows affected is dependent on the rows in the recordset. If the recordset is 5 rows long, then the first 5 rows of 'Sheet1' are reformatted. If it is 10 rows long, then the first 10. This problem occurs with both Office 2013 and 2016.

Update: I Changed the Range for the CopyFromRecordset functions to only refer to the upper left hand cell of the paste range. Now, rather than affecting all column of Sheet1, it is only noticeably affecting a single column. "Column N" for what it's worth.

Answer (score 5):

There's an issue with `copyfromrecordset` where when it copies in data (dates specifically) it formats the `activesheet` rather than the target sheet.

I've worked around this by simply activating the target sheet before copying, in your case:

```
Dim adRs As ADODB.Recordset
Set adRs = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim SQLQuery As String  
SQLQuery = "SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM Table;"
On Error GoTo OpenFailed
adRs.Open SQLQuery, adConn, adOpenStatic, adLockPessimistic         

Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate

If Not (adRs.BOF And adRs.EOF) Then
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:O300").CopyFromRecordset adRs
End If
```

I've found this hasn't drastically slowed down the performance on mine.  If you needed to revert the active sheet back to the one you're working in you could use this:

```
Dim adRs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim WS as Worksheet
Set adRs = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim SQLQuery As String  
SQLQuery = "SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM Table;"
On Error GoTo OpenFailed
adRs.Open SQLQuery, adConn, adOpenStatic, adLockPessimistic         

Set WS = ActiveSheet
Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate

If Not (adRs.BOF And adRs.EOF) Then
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:O300").CopyFromRecordset adRs
End If
WS.Activate
```